# Error "<url> is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Tags: c++, runtime-error

My code should take arguments, put "+" inbetween them, and search google chrome with this, however I get the error (Command line Argument= "Stack Overflow Site"):

> http://www.google.com/search?q=Stack+Overflow+Site'C:\Program' is not
>   recognized  as an internal or external command, operable program or
>   batch file.

Also in my program I get this error:

> error C4996: 'strcpy': This function or variable may be unsafe.
>   Consider using strcpy_s instead. To disable deprecation, use
>   _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details. c:\users\user\documents\visual studio
>   2013\projects\project1\project1\main.cpp
>   I have been ignoring this, because I thought it was just a warning, but I'm not sure if it is relevant.

My code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    //Loop through arguments and put a "+" between them.
    string out = "";
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {
        if (i != 1){
            out += "+";
        }
        out += argv[i];
    }
    string newout = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe \"http://www.google.com/search?q=" + out + "\"";

    // set the size of the structures
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

    //set y to newout and convert
    char *y = new char[newout.length() + 1];
    strcpy(y, newout.c_str());

    //Run Google Chrome with argument
    CreateProcessA("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe",   // the path
        y,        // Command line
        NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
        NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
        FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
        0,              // No creation flags
        NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
        NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory 
        &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
        &pi           // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
        );
    delete[] y;
    cin.ignore();
}
```

Comment: The **relevant** portions of your code need to be here, in the question itself, and not off-site. If the relevant details are off-site, and that off-site location is unavailable (moved, deleted, or off-line) your question has zero value to future readers here.  Note the emphasis on **relevant portions of your code**.

Comment: You used `y` after deleting it and doing so is very bad. Deleting must be after finished using. Also note that using `CreateProcessA` is better to explicitly use ANSI charset version.

Comment: @MikeCAT, I have made the changes you suggested, but I still have the same errors in my code.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are not getting exactly the same error since you
stopped deleting the commandline buffer before using it, but
some different, equally unexpected result.

If you will read [the documentation of `CreateProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx)
you will learn that the parameters:

```
_In_opt_    LPCTSTR               lpApplicationName,
_Inout_opt_ LPTSTR                lpCommandLine,
```

can be supplied in one of three ways, as illustrated:-

**Way 1**

```
lpApplicationName = "\path\to\executable"
lpCommandLine = "args for the executable"
```

which results in a process initiated with the command:

```
\path\to\executable args for the executable
```

**Way 2**

```
lpApplicationName = NULL 
lpCommandLine = "\path\to\executable args for the executable"
```

which results in the same process as **Way 1**

**Way 3**

```
lpApplicationName = "\path\to\executable" 
lpCommandLine = NULL
```

which results in a process initiated with the command `\path\to\executable`.

You are not using **Way 1** or **Way 2** or **Way 3**, but:

```
lpApplicationName = "\path\to\executable" 
lpCommandLine = "\path\to\executable args for the executable"
```

which in your case results in a process initiated with the command:

```
"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe \
C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe \
http://www.google.com/search?q=Stack+Overflow+Site"
```

in which the arguments passed to Chrome are:

```
C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe \
http://www.google.com/search?q=Stack+Overflow+Site"
```

Of course this does not have the anticipated outcome.

Should you wish to correct this by adopting **Way 2**, bear particularly
in mind what the documentation says about `lpCommandLine`:

> ...
>   If lpApplicationName is NULL, the first white space–delimited token of the command line specifies the module name.
>   ...